# Smooth motion between waypoints in ROS navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have an application where I am using the turtlebot simulator with move_base for some navigation related tasks. So generally, if a goal is specified, I am assuming the nav stack comes up with a spline for a large set of points that when passed through, take the robot there.  If I have my own (sufficiently large) set of waypoints; is there a way to avoid stopping at every waypoint and rather let the robot drive through them like a curve?

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95321/smooth-motion-between-waypoints-in-ros-navigation/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

trajectory controllers are not for robot base, they are for robot arms. During the navigation move_base takes global planner and local planner into account for avoiding collisions with obstacles thus you don't follow the exact path during robot base navigation. If you want your robot base to follow exact path you can code your own controller. You can check out [pr2_controller tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_controllers/Tutorials) for details in order to write your own controller for the base

And local planners such as dwa ( that is in ros ) does what you need check out this [this wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-10-30**:
Thank you!